# How to delete messageboard of Rails Thredded forum engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I've been integrated Thredded into my rails app. It is the first forum engine I've tried, and it is cool. Just recently, I am willing to completely remove some messageboards, but the messageboards controller itself does not have the destroy action. I've tried adding it manually, and it leads me to override more and more classes, models, etc, yet with no success.

Any clues would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete a Thredded messageboard from the command line or the Rails console.

For example, if the messageboard's URL slug is "url-slug":

```bash
rails r "Thredded::Messageboard.friendly_find!('url-slug').destroy!"
```

Comment: Thanks @glebm for quick response! However, in my case, I want to have a delete function on client site similar to delete topic funtion.

Comment: Hi again @glebm! I've tried removing record through rails console but not succeed due to fk references.

`update or delete on table "thredded_messageboards" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_966803d714" on table "thredded_messageboard_users"`

Comment: You've found a bug! It is now fixed on master, but until the next version is out, simply create and run a migration that has the same code as this one: https://github.com/thredded/thredded/blob/7865de3ee607c8b710b98b1edb4ac23abca95070/db/upgrade_migrations/20170125033319_upgrade_v0_9_to_v0_10.rb

Comment: This is fixed as your suggested migrations. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @glebm!
I've just come up with this error using change for the migration. `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration: ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration`

I simply fixed this by using up and down method instead. (Up method for `add_foreign_key` while Down method for `remove_foreign_key`)